# jquery ajax delay form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, delay

I have this jquery ajax code that submits my form if it gets changed. My only problem is that I also have a country jquery selection in my form and everytime i click on the autocomplete suggestion the form with the old/last value get's submitted.
Example: I search for "Austria" and click on it and an empty value gets submitted. Then I change it to "Poland" and "at" for Austria is submitted.
My idea is to delay the ajax call: $.ajax but I couldn't find out how.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function submitFormAjax()
{
    $('#myForm').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"ajax.php",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                $("#ajaxList").html(data);

            }
        })

      return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will work, hard to tell without seeing more of the code, but here's how to delay the $.ajax !

```
$('#myForm').on('change', function() {
   setTimeout(submitFormAjax, 200);
   return false;
});
function submitFormAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:$('#myForm').serialize(),
        success:function(data) {
            $("#ajaxList").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout will do the work here:

```
$('#myForm').change(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"ajax.php",
            data:self.serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                $("#ajaxList").html(data);

            }
        })
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Okay the delay works with that code but now I have a:
Notice: Undefined index: country
The country textfield stays NULL now
just checked it again, the whole form doesn't submit, just this notice gets added...

Comment: you need to bind the callback so that `this` points to the form. Set `var $self = $(this);` on line 2, then change data to $self.serialize()

Comment: Thanks @rjz! Made the changes accordingly.

Comment: Hopefully that fixes it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myForm').change(function() {
 var val = $(this).serialize();
 setTimeout(delayAjax(val),1000);
});
```

define the delay ajax function

```
function delayAjax(formVal){

 $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"ajax.php",
            data:formVal,
            success:function(data)
            {
                $("#ajaxList").html(data);
            }
        });
};
```